# How do you enable text selection in ChromeOS app windows?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have created a packaged application for Chrome OS. Everything is running great, however, I am unable to select any text in my window. I have some DIV's that I would like my users to select text from, but I can't seem to figure it out. Honestly, I really don't care if users can select text globally or not -- i just want it to work.

Is there some sort of chrome.app.window property or special class I need to use? I am running the latest ChromeOS on my Acer C720.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving the following style to whatever div you want to enable text selection works:

```
-webkit-user-select: text
```